# Extract data inside nested braces

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract content between the first nested braces and second nested braces separately. Now I am totally stuck with this can anyone help me. My file read.txt contains the below data . I just read that to a string "s".

```
  BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("read.txt"));
    while(br.ready())
    {
        String s=br.readLine();
        System.out.println(s);

    }
```

Output

```
{ { "John", "ran" },                { "NOUN", "VERB" } },
{ { "The", "dog", "jumped"},        { "DET", "NOUN", "VERB" } },
{ {  "Mike","lives","in","Poland"}, {"NOUN","VERB","DET","NOUN"} },
```

ie my output should look like

```
  "John", "ran"    
  "NOUN", "VERB" 
  "The", "dog", "jumped"  
  "DET", "NOUN", "VERB" 
  "Mike","lives","in","Poland" 
  "NOUN","VERB","DET","NOUN"
```

Comment: Regular expressions are not suited for this task. You will have to write (or find) a proper parser. It should not be very hard, since the format is more or less fixed.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin i have edited my question since it was unclear. Now its   fixed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
(?<=\{)(?!\s*\{)[^{}]+
```

See the matches in the [Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dU5lQ3/5).

In Java:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\{)(?!\\s*\\{)[^{}]+");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    // matched text: regexMatcher.group()
}
```

**Explanation**

- The lookbehind `(?<=\{)` asserts that what precedes the current position is a `{`
- The negative lookahead `(?!\s*\{)` asserts that what follows is not optional whitespace then `{`
- `[^{}]+` matches any chars that are not curlies

Comment: This does my head in.

Comment: FYI: Added explanation. :)

Comment: aww, horrible that regex.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant What makes you say that?

Comment: @zx81 the fact that `(?<=\{)(?!\s*\{)[^{}]+` is supposed to do/mean something sensible and easy to reason about...

Comment: Ahh, it's really easy. You just need to read a good tutorial like [this one](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html) :)

Comment: @zx81 looks like you assume I don't know regular expressions. I do. It's just that I find them awful.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Sorry, I misunderstood your earlier comment.

Comment: @zx81 Now it works very well. thank u ...sorry 4 the late rply

Answer (score 3):

If you split on "}," then you get your sets of words in a single string, then just a matter of replacing curly braces

As per your code

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("read.txt"));
while(br.ready())
{
    String s=br.readLine();
    String [] words = s.split ("},");

    for (int x = 0; x < words.length; x++) {
        String printme = words[x].replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
    }

}
```

Comment: Scary a small edit is there String printme = words[x].replace("{","").replace("}","");

Answer (score 1):

You could always remove the opening brackets, then split by '},' which would leave you with the list of strings you've asked for. (If that is all one string, of course)

```
String s = input.replace("{","");
String[] splitString = s.split("},");
```

Would first remove open brackets:

```
"John", "ran" },                "NOUN", "VERB" } },
"The", "dog", "jumped"},        "DET", "NOUN", "VERB" } },
"Mike","lives","in","Poland"},"NOUN","VERB","DET","NOUN"} },
```

Then would split by },

```
"John", "ran"
"NOUN", "VERB" }
"The", "dog", "jumped"
"DET", "NOUN", "VERB" }
"Mike","lives","in","Poland"
"NOUN","VERB","DET","NOUN"}
```

Then you just need to tidy them up with another replace!

Comment: A small mistake is there because closing bracket is still there   System.out.println(splitString[i].replace("}", ""));

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be searching for `{...}` substring with no inner `{` or `}` characters and take only its inner part without `{` and `}`.

Regex describing such substring can look like

```
\\{(?<content>[^{}]+)\\}
```

Explanation:

- `\\{` is escaped `{` so now it represents `{` literal (normally it represents start of quantifier `{x,y}` so it needed to be escaped)
- `(?<content>...)` is named-capturing group, it will store only part between `{` and `}` and later we would be able to use this part (instead of entire match which would also include `{` `}`)
- `[^{}]+` represents one or more non `{` `}` characters
- `\\}` escaped `}` which means it represents `}`

DEMO:

```
String input = "{ { \"John\", \"ran\" },                { \"NOUN\", \"VERB\" } },\r\n" + 
        "{ { \"The\", \"dog\", \"jumped\"},        { \"DET\", \"NOUN\", \"VERB\" } },\r\n" + 
        "{ {  \"Mike\",\"lives\",\"in\",\"Poland\"}, {\"NOUN\",\"VERB\",\"DET\",\"NOUN\"} },";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{(?<content>[^{}]+)\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group("content").trim());
}
```

Output:

```
"John", "ran"
"NOUN", "VERB"
"The", "dog", "jumped"
"DET", "NOUN", "VERB"
"Mike","lives","in","Poland"
"NOUN","VERB","DET","NOUN"
```